# Return data only from one table after JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table A and B and I want to get only rows from table A which user_id is also in table B and which have expire date in table B smaller than CURRENT_TIME + 6 months.

```
SELECT * from u_uzivatele JOIN bw_paid_orders
      ON u_uzivatele.id = bw_paid_orders.user_id 
WHERE bw_paid_orders.active_thru < NOW() + interval '6 months'
```

This query does that, but it returns all columns from A and also from B, I want to get only columns from A.

Comment: Select the columns from A : `select * from` -> `select A.col1, A.col2, ...`

Comment: `SELECT u_uzivatele .* from...`

Comment: you can name your columns like Ben H told you it's the simplest way to do it

Comment: @VaoTsun that answer worked, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.* 
from u_uzivatele as a
JOIN bw_paid_orders b ON a.id = b.user_id 
WHERE b.active_thru < NOW() + interval '6 months
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
SELECT u_uzivatele.* FROM u_uzivatele 
JOIN bw_paid_orders ON u_uzivatele.id = bw_paid_orders.user_id 
WHERE bw_paid_orders.active_thru < NOW() + interval '6 months'
```

Get all columns from `u_uzivatele`.
Or pass the bw_paid_orders table instead if you want the columns from there.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT a.* FROM u_uzivatele a JOIN bw_paid_orders b
      ON a.id = b.user_id 
WHERE b.active_thru < NOW() + INTERVAL '6 months'
```